# Cannot coerce between type 49 and type 31

Tags: json, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I have a problem to append a json_array_t to another json_array_t in Pl/SQL 12c. I have the following code:

`v_method_resp_arr.append(JSON_OBJECT_T(JSON_OBJECT('NAME' VALUE v_method, 'DETAIL' VALUE v_method_det_arr)));`

Where `v_method_resp_arr` and `v_method_det_arr` are `json_array_t`. I receive the following error code:

> Error: PLS-00801: internal error [*** ASSERT at file pdw4.c, line  909;
> Cannot coerce between type 49 and type 31;

Another method is to define a new variable v_method_resp_obj JSON_OBJECT_T and store the info there and then append this object to array, but I want to avoid using an auxiliary variable.

`v_method_resp_obj.put('NAME',v_method); v_method_resp_obj.put('DETAIL',v_method_det_arr); v_method_resp_arr.append(v_method_resp_obj);`

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] including an executable PL/SQL block that demonstrates the issue and, if the PL/SQL block is not self-contained then the DDL/DML statements for the SQL tables & data needed to replicate the issue. Without that, we are guessing on how you managed to generate the error. So, please help us to help you by making it easy to replicate the issue (and generating a minimal example may help you to find the solution).

Comment: PLS-00801 is a generic error, which Oracle hurls when it encounters an exception which it cannot handle or even describe. That is, a bug. The official advice is to report this error as a bug to your Oracle Support. However, that's not much help if you do not have a Support contract. So your options are to search the internet for somebody who has had this precise error and posted a solution. Or change your code until you get something which achieves your desired outcome without throwing an error. If you expect further help from us you need to post a complete reproducible test case.

Comment: For what it's worth, someone appears to have this exact issue with XML and solved it with a re-write. This won't directly help you but it underscores my previous comment. [Check it out](https://www.databaseusers.com/article/9473548/PLS-00801%3A+internal+error+%5B***+ASSERT+at+file+pdw4.c%2C+line%C2%A0+796%3B).

Comment: Type 31 and Type 49 are not listed in OCI nor XML headers nor can be found in documentation - must be not published internal type codes https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnoci/data-types.html#GUID-D69455D9-CE01-44CC-B5A9-E541C7774805

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this has changed in newer releases, but on 12c you cannot use JSON_OBJECT in PL/SQL.

Also, JSON_OBJECT_T "put" is a procedure, so it can't be used to add key/value pairs without being instantiated first as a variable.

That leaves 3 ways to do what you need, as far as I know:

1. As you already said in your original post, create another variable to be used as the append argument:

```
declare
  ja json_array_t;
  jo json_object_t;
  v_method varchar2(15) := 'method name';
  v_method_det_arr varchar2( 30 ) := 'some details here';
begin
  ja := json_array_t;
  jo := json_object_t;
  jo.put( 'name', v_method );
  jo.put( 'detail', v_method_det_arr );
  ja.append( jo );
  dbms_output.put_line(ja.to_string);
end;
```

2. Build the json object using JSON_OBJECT_T's parse constructor, who will return the object back, allowing it's use without instantiating a new variable:

> two problems with this approach though: It is probably the worst performing and most prone to errors solution, since you will have to concatenate the parameters together as a JSON string to be parsed and returned as a JSON_OBJECT_T.

```
declare
  ja json_array_t;
  v_method varchar2(15) := 'method name';
  v_method_det_arr varchar2( 30 ) := 'some details here';
begin
  ja := json_array_t;
  ja.append( json_object_t( '{name:"' || v_method  || '", detail:"' || v_method_det_arr  || '"}' ) );
  dbms_output.put_line(ja.to_string);
end;
```

3. Build the JSON string in SQL:

```
declare
  v_method varchar2(15) := 'method name';
  v_method_det_arr varchar2( 30 ) := 'some details here';
  v_json_string clob;
begin
  select json_arrayagg
         ( json_object
           ( 'name' value v_method
           , 'detail' value v_method_det_arr
           )
         )
  into   v_json_string
  from   dual
  ;

  dbms_output.put_line( dbms_lob.substr( v_json_string, 200, 1 ) );
end;
```

I would believe solution #3 would be the best if you have no need to manipulate the JSON array further or use it as a JSON_ARRAY_T return value for your function, especially if you will be looping through the results of a query to generate the array.

Otherwise - though more verbose - I believe solution #1 would be a more readable and performant approach.